# Spark Sql Query On Nested Records. I want to do Filter nested array of records first and then explode(expand them into rows)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, parquet

I want to first filter only the rows which have Max and then i want to explode only rows that have Max in the nested column.

My Avro Record:

```
{
"name": "Parent",
"type":"record",
"fields":[
    {"name": "firstname", "type": "string"},

    {
        "name":"children",
        "type":{
            "type": "array",
            "items":{
                        "name":"child",
                        "type":"record",
                        "fields":[

                       {"name":"name", "type":"string"}                                                                    
                       {"name":"price","type":["long", "null"]}

                        ]
                    }
            }
    }
]
}
```

I am using Spark SQL context to query dataframe which is read. So if input is

```
Row no   Firstname Children.name
    1    John       [[Max, 20],[Pg, 22]]
    2    Bru        [[huna, 10], [aman, 12]]
```

I query first by exploding inner table. So nested column split into 2 rows.

```
Row no   Firstname Children.name    children.price
        1    John       Max               20
        1    John       Pg                22
        2    Bru        huna              10
        2    Bru        aman              12
```

q1)I want to first filter only the rows which have Max and then i want to explode only rows that have Max in it. In the current situation, if i have million of values in one column, than it first generate the million rows, and then check if Max is present.

q2) I want to first filter only the rows which have price > 12 and then i want to explode only rows that have price > 12 in it. In the current situation, if i have million of values in one column, than it first generate the million rows, and then check if price > 12 is present.

Something like this:
 **val results = sqlc.sql("SELECT firstname, child.name FROM parent LATERAL VIEW explode(children) childTable AS child where child.price > 12")**

Comment: Filter on children name containing max to create a new Dataframe  and then explode. Have you tried that ?

Comment: The following query doesn't work

val results = sqlc.sql("SELECT firstname, children.name FROM parent where children.name = 'Max'")

Comment: I said contains not equals. You can find all the sql functions that you can use in the spark scala doc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35628252/1560062

Comment: Also please review your other questions ! They are hanging unresolved for now.

Comment: Thanxs @zero323 .   I have used array_contains for string but I also want to apply an expression on filed like price. There is no inbuilt function in spark-sql doc.

Comment: Thanxs @eliasah for the array_contains method.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the ans to the two questions: 
ans1) **If you want to find if "string" exist in a array of nested records:**

```
var results = sqlc.sql("SELECT firstname, children.name  FROM parent where array_contains(children['name'], 'pg') ")
```

ans2) **if you want to apply a condition on array of nested records. Using UDF**

```
sqlc.udf.register("myPriceFilter", (price: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => (price exists (a =>  (a.toLong < 67735) )))

var results = sqlc.sql("SELECT firstname, explode(children.price)  FROM parent where myPriceFilter(children['price']) ")
```